# Cannot Set Property on Undefined Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a property on an object I haven't created yet. It doesn't seem to want to let me add properties on the fly, and it must be done this way. Why am I receiving the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'someItem.anotherProperty = "someOtherValue"')
```

I don't understand why I cannot dynamically set properties on the variable `someItem`. Isn't the whole point of Javascript that I can add whatever I want whenever I want to an object (in this case `someItem`)?

Here's my code:

```
testObject = function () {
    var someItem;
    someItem.anotherProperty = "someOtherValue";

    function doStuff () {
        someItem.someProperty = "someValue";
    }

};

function start () {
    item = new testObject();
    item.doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the first line to this `var someItem = {};` as the the variables are `undefined` by default, if no values are assigned to them while initializing. And `undefined` is not an object to be set with properties and hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

`someItem` when declared as just `var someItem` is `undefined` in JS. Change the declaration to 
`var someItem = {};`

Answer (score 1):

change `var someItem;` to `var someItem = {};`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            testObject = function () {

                var someItem = {};  //changed

                someItem.anotherProperty = "someOtherValue";

                function doStuff () {

                    someItem.someProperty = "someValue";

                };

            };

            function start () {

                item = new testObject();

                item.doStuff();

            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="start();"></body>
</html>
```